# Get key-value from Mutable Map in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I have created mutable state map using an atom. I would like to get the value of the key from the map.
I have tried it in the below way, But it returns "nil" value

```
(def coll1 (atom {}) )
(swap! coll1 assoc :a "XXXX" :b "XXXXXX")
```

This statement printing

```
(println coll1)

#object[clojure.lang.Atom 0x771a660 {:status :ready, :val {:a XXXX, :b XXXXXX}}]
```

I have written this statement to fetch value of :a

```
(println (get-in coll1 [:val :a]))
```

Comment: you just forgot to deref the atom: (println (get-in @coll1 [:val :a]))

Comment: `:val` isn't the key that should be referenced. Just deref the atom and get `:a` key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to dereference the atom. This [link](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/atom) will help. 
For your case, you are looking for something like `(get @coll1 :a)` or `(:a @coll1)` or `(@coll1 :a)`